# Rails error with angular js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to create a button and on that button I have created a popup with angularjs. When I am using normal html tag it is opening the popup properly .But When I am converting in rails tag the popup gets dissapear within 1 sec and automatically the pages gets redirected to some other page .I have never use angularJs..Any solution will be helpful

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="deviceregisteration($event)">Add New Device</button>
```

So my this rails code is creating problem as I have mention above

```
<%= f.submit 'Add New Device',:class =>'btn btn-primary btn-lg'  ,'ng-click'=>"deviceregisteration($event)" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your button made the popup disappeared is that it submitted the form.

Your plain `HTML` way, that button is simply a button, nothing more, so when you hit that button, it triggered the event.

When you used `rails code`, that button is a **submit button**, when you click on, it triggered the event and also submit the form and redirect to another page due to the response.

To fix this, you can just use `f.button` instead of `f.submit`.